# I have a:"TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle is not an object." but cant get it isolated

Tags: jquery, firefox

Pre: I am pretty sure, that there is a subtle Firefox bug, but I cant get it isolated, I am asking for help to achieve this.

So this is strange:

The following 'problem': I expanded my (ruby) page for EU - cookie story, but thats not the point; I now got the situation, that everything works with (almost) all browsers and (almost) all pages.

*except* on *one* page on FireFox, where I get `"TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle is not an object."` Other pages work as expected (same template, same logic)

I get this error only if i use `$().show()` *and* `css: display:none;`  together. If I remark `display: none;` for sample: no error, if I remark (or delete) `.show()`: no error

I have found a workaround, (I use `visibility: hidden;` but I am still sure, that it is not my fault, and that I should tell to FF bug fixing, but I can reproduce the error only on one - my home page (not online yet)

I dont get any other errors.

the css looks like this: (excerpt)

```
div#site-cookie-alarm {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  ...
```

the jquery looks like this: (excerpt and the workaround is here)

```
 h=$('div#site-cookie-alarm').height() #just a workaround
 $('div#site-cookie-alarm').show().height(0).css("visibility","visible").animate({height:h}, 1000)
```

any Idea, what to try, to isolate the prblem?

*EDIT:*
sry, forgot: FF is 29.0.1 on windows 7/64

*EDIT added Debugging Info*

jQuery tries to determine the default (browsers) value for `display` if it is `display:none;`

```
function css_defaultDisplay( nodeName ) {
   var doc = document,
   display = elemdisplay[ nodeName ];
   if ( !display ) {
      display = actualDisplay( nodeName, doc );
```

in there it tries to create the `div`

```
// Called ONLY from within css_defaultDisplay
function actualDisplay( name, doc ) {
   var elem = jQuery( doc.createElement( name ) ).appendTo( doc.body ), 
        display = jQuery.css( elem[0], "display" );
```

Creates a copy of itself (?)

```
 // Define a local copy of jQuery
jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
   // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
   return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
   },
```

back to actualDisplay where elem is now an empty object, so `elem[0]` is `undefined`, too
there is the `undefined` `elem`

```
getStyles(elem=undefined)jquery.js?body=1
curCSS(elem=undefined, name="display", _computed=undefined)jquery.js?body=1 
css(elem=undefined, name="display", extra=undefined, styles=undefined)jquery.js?body=1
```

---

```
actualDisplay(name="div", doc=Document ?locale=de)jquery.js?body=1
css_defaultDisplay(nodeName="div")jquery.js?body=1
showHide(elements=Object[div#site-cookie-alarm], show=true)jquery.js?body=1
show()jquery.js?body=1
(?)(speed=undefined, easing=undefined, callback=undefined)jquery.js?body=1
step_through(step_number=0)site_c...?body=1 
(?)()?locale=de (Zeile 4)
```

Comment: Use firebug to set a breakpoint at the error, reload page and then look at what is being passed as second argument and from where.

Comment: Or learn to google for bugs : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=987098

Comment: @Anthony: I was there "I can reproduce this locally pretty often (2-4 times out of 10). But with a sleep(500) before getting the button from the popup blocker, the failures are gone.", I have 100% on my page, and no timing problem (this was not ok)

Comment: @Anthony: it stops at `window.getComputedStyle( elem, null );` and elem _is_ `undefined`

Comment: @halfbit OK, where did `elem` come from in that case?

Comment: @BorisZbarsky: I put the Info into the Question; BTW: I just wanted _not_ to debug jQuery :-D

Comment: @halfbit I totally understand not wanting to debug jQuery....  If you're not using the most recent version of it, you might want to see if doing that fixes things, though.  Sometimes they do have bugs.